# MATLAB - Convert string to mathematical function

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to make application in Matlab which will take user input as string, convert it to mathematical function and plot it.

Problem is, I don't know how to convert string to math function.
This is what I have tried:

```
f = get(handles.edit1, 'string');
n=0:length(f)-1;
func = str2func(f);
plot(n,func);
```

So if user inputs `sin(x)` it should be ploted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by using `ezplot`:

```
f = get(handles.edit1, 'string');
ezplot(f)
```

This code can plot any y(x) function.

Answer (score 3):

normally you need to specify the values at which you plot the function if that's not an issue then I would replace plot with [ezplot](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ezplot.html)

also assuming the function takes only one variable

```
f = get(handles.edit1, 'string');
a = strfind(f,'(')-1;
func = str2func(f(1:a));
ezplot(func)
```

if you need a range of values to plot the function at i would use [fplot](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fplot.html) instead

```
fplot(func,limits)
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning ezplot. After studying docs for ezplot I found out I can solve my problem like this: f = get(handles.edit1, 'string');
ezplot(f). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use [eval](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eval.html)

```
f = get(handles.edit1, 'string');
n=0:10;
plot(n,eval(f));
```